# Best way to update/store a basic table in Azure, after Azure Function fires?

Tags: python, azure

I have a Twitter bot ([here's the GitHub](https://github.com/papelr/BadCelebBotAzureFunction_v2.1) page). It has two `TimerTrigger` functions (that rely on Tweepy), that each create and push Tweets. Pretty simple, it works, and it costs basically nothing. My question: what's the best method to capture those Tweets in a table? (First column would be Tweet ID, second col would be the first Twitter handle, third col would be the Tweet text, etc.)

I have read about creating some sort of Blob storage function that fires when another function fires (or HTTP, but I think this should be more simple than that) - but I'd really prefer to just use a script in a shared code folder (to instantiate in my `__init__.py` scripts) to capture & store each Tweet as they get fired off into the Twitterverse. Azure provides [this sample code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/azure-data-tables_12.3.0/sdk/tables/azure-data-tables/samples/sample_update_upsert_merge_entities.py), which I think is pretty good, but I have no idea of the best place to stick it.

Comment: it depends on how/what you need to read/query. e.g. will you retrieve all tweets from a particular date? from a particular user? fulltext search on all tweets?

Comment: For now, I simply want to store them. Learn how to walk before running. Since the bot replies/tags handles randomly, I'll probably end up creating some process where it does not use the same handle again, but that's for the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [Azure Tables client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/data-tables-readme?view=azure-python) you can access **Azure Storage Tables** and CosmosDB. I think for what you are trying to do, the simplest (and more cost effective solution) is to use Azure Storage Tables.

```
from azure.data.tables import TableServiceClient
from datetime import datetime

TWEET_ID = u'001234'
HANDLE = u'RedMarker'

my_entity = {
    u'PartitionKey': HANDLE,
    u'RowKey': TWEET_ID,
    u'TweetText': u"blah.....blah....blah"
}

table_service_client = TableServiceClient.from_connection_string(conn_str="<connection_string>")
table_client = table_service_client.get_table_client(table_name="myTable")

entity = table_client.create_entity(entity=my_entity)
```

Comment: That's straightforward and easy - but on creating the table itself, does this script just re-create the table every time, or does it append to it? Or does the `create_entity` just stash that particular row into the already created table? Thank you sir!

Comment: Table is not created in this script it only creates a table client instance based off the connection string.  Table create sample is here: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/storage-table-python-getting-started/blob/master/table_basic_samples.py#L46